# debugging info for Mac System Python - how to get line numbers

Tags: python, macos, dwarf

When I have a some crash report including some MacOSX library (in this case, I'm mostly interested in Python), how can I get more info about it? The library does not contain the debugging information, so the crash report lacks line numbers and other useful stuff. Can I get the debugging information elsewhere and reconstruct the line numbers?

Comment: Do you mean when an exception is thrown in Python or when the Python interpreter actually crashes (which (ideally) shouldn't ever happen)?

Comment: A crash report happens only when it really crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the lldb debugger.  It is scriptable in python and pretty easy to do things like symbolicating a crash report.  There is even an included example python script that can symbolicate a standard Mac OS X crash report (assuming you have dSYMs for some of the frameworks) and provide file name & line number information.

See http://lldb.llvm.org/symbolication.html for more information about using this, or it is easy to write your own python scripts with lldb.  You can make a python method that is called from an lldb session (like `lldb.macosx.crashlog` does), or you can write a standalone python script that loads lldb and does whatever you want.  lldb is structured like a library (a framework on Mac OS X), the `lldb` command-line command is one possible client of LLDB.framework.